# Unable to write the existing text file in RobotFramework

Tags: python, text-files, robotframework

Unable to write the existing text file in RobotFramework.
My target to get output from for loop and write the value in text file, currently i'm able to create text file and printing the output value from for loop, but unable to write the value in text file.

What I have tried:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           OperatingSystem

*** Variables ***
${PATH}           ${CURDIR}/write_one_to_five.txt

*** Test Cases ***
For_Loop
    Create File    ${PATH}    # Text file created at current directory
    : FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    1    6
    \    Log    ${i}
    File Should Exist    ${PATH}    ${i}
    Log    Exited
```

Comment: Are you aware of the documentation site of Robot Framework: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/? Here you'll find the full documentation for all the included libraries like [Operatingsystem](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html).

Comment: Yes I'm, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use keyword **Append To File** from **Operating system library** http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html

Did some little modification in your code using the **Append To File** keyword and it worked!!

```
*** Settings ***
Library           OperatingSystem

*** Variables ***
${PATH}           ${CURDIR}/write_one_to_five.txt

*** Test Cases ***
For_Loop
    Create File    ${PATH}    # Text file created at current directory
    : FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    1  6
    \    log to console  ${i}
    \    ${b}=  Convert To String  ${i}     #conversion was required as it was throwing encoding error for integer
    \    Append To File  write_one_to_five.txt  ${b}
    #File Should Exist    ${PATH}    ${i}      #This was causing error to me, hence commented
    Log    Exited
```